# Inequalities - AM-GM

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, contest-math, means, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $H_n = 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + ... + \frac1n$

Prove that;

$H_n + n$ $\geq$ n$(n+1)^\frac{1}{n}$
for $n$ $\leq$ $2$

I have tried writing $H_n + n = \frac12 + \frac13 +...+ \frac1n + (n+1)$ but am left with an $n!$ in the denominator after applying AM-GM. I have also tried $H_n + n +1 + 2 + 3 + ... +n$ but this does not work either.

I am looking for hints put me on the right track, note, i need to solve this using AM-GM.

Comment: Do you mean $n \le 2$?

Comment: @Henry I don't think he does. He probably means $n \ge 2$, though I'm not sure.

Comment: @MXYMXY: It looks as if $H_n +n \ge n\,(n+1)^{1/n}$ for all positive integer $n$ using your hint.  The difference seems to tend to $\gamma$ as $n$ increases

Comment: @Henry But using that it tends to $\gamma$ is hardly using AM-GM..is it? To my understanding,  after calculus AM-GM can be ridiculously easily proved using Jensen, so I think that a precalculus method would be better.

Comment: @MXYMXY - indeed, and $\gamma$ is irrelevant as you only need to show the difference is non-negative.  While it is well known that $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} H_n-\log_e(n) = \gamma$, I had not been aware that  $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}  n\,(n+1)^{1/n} - \log_e(n) -n =0$

Answer (score 7):

**HINT**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}+n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k}$$

Realize that $\frac{k+1}{k}\times \frac{k+2}{k+1}=\frac{k+2}{k}$.

Now, it's much simpler to use AM-GM since the multiples cancel each other out.